# ¿Quisiera migrar mi proyecto de Laravel 5.3 a Laravel 5.4, si lo hago dañaría mi proyecto?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Se que de 5.1 a 5.2 hay funciones diferentes, de 5.2 a 5.3 tambien es el caso, ¿habría un problema si yo cambio de 5.3 a 5.4?

Comment: Realmente depende, la respuesta la encuentras en la documentación y en tu código actual.

Comment: Si tienes pruebas unitarias, deberías migrar en un sandbox (como una maquina virtual) y correr las pruebas. Si fallan.... GGWP

Comment: @Shaz ¿y donde veo esa parte?

Answer (score -1):

para migrar de Laravel 5.3 a 5.4 debes [revisar la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0) para ver qué cambios debes hacer para no dañar tu proyecto. La verdad es que los cambios no son muchos, no te debe costar tanto hacer la actualización.

Ten en cuenta que tal vez debas actualizar las librerías que uses para que también sean compatibles con Laravel 5.4, lo cual no es más que revisar la documentación de cada una y cambiar a las correspondientes versiones en tu archivo `composer.json`.